# How to target a devops branch when script creating objects in ADFv2?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

Using azure data factory v2 with GIT / Azure DevOps integration:
If you for example create a trigger using Set-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger via powershell according to the documentation, the trigger is created directly in the adf_publish branch. This is an issue, as this will result in a mismatch between the master branch and adf_publish, meaning you'll not be able to publish going forward as this of course raises an error. How do I get the cmdlet to create the trigger in a new or specific branch, which I then can merge into master and publish the correct way?

Comment: I am struggling with the same thing. Were you able to resolve this? Also, I checked the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/set-azdatafactoryv2trigger?view=azps-3.7.0 but did not find any reference to the adf_publish branch. Can you tell me where you found the info that the trigger is created directly in the adf_publish branch?

Comment: I found out by doing it, and it created stuff in the adf_publish branch which then went out-of-sync with my master branch. I have no solution at this point.

Comment: That's not how it works for Az Powershell and ADF, if you want the trigger created in your branch rather than the actual adf_publish branch (Physical ADF) then you will have to develop code that will drop the Json File for that trigger into one of your branches. If you do this, then it will not throw an out of sync. I'm not sure why you'd want to do this though, first create the trigger in your feature branch, then PR to collab, then publish to actual ADF.... if you really have to use powershell to create triggers in your branch then use the Azure DevOps REST API to create a trigger file