# Azure Datafactory export ARM template via CLI/API/PowerShell

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way to export ARM template from particular (not collaboration) branch via CLI/API/PowerShell?

I haven't found it in docs, only UI way, but it doesn't feet my needs

Comment: You can use PowerShell command `Export-AzResourceGroup` to export resource : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/export-azresourcegroup?view=azps-3.8.0

Comment: It will export ARM template of all ADF, but I need it to be exported from particular branch

Comment: Sort of related to my question here. People from MS edited the question but didn't answer it. Guess there's no support. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983239/how-to-target-a-devops-branch-when-script-creating-objects-in-adfv2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not supported currently. Please feel free to comment and/or up-vote the below feature request shared by other users. Doing so will help to increase the priority of feature request.

ADF Feature Request link: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/35327899-add-powershell-cmdlet-support-for-import-export-ar